# How can I detect the subsystem used when my program was compiled?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

How can I detect whether my Win32 / Win64 program was compiled with /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS, or  /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE?

A preprocessor method would be best if it already exists, but I'd also like to know how to detect it at runtime. It would be sufficient to just detect if there is a console associated with the app, as long as it returns true for console apps.

I'm doing this because I have code to make a console window appear for debugging my GUI apps, but I also build them in console mode (in which case I do not spawn a new console window), and don't really want to make/manage a new #define for this when it seems like there has to already be a way to determine this.

Comment: `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` is a linker, not a compiler option. That's why you can't detect it at compile time - too early.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since in your setting you desire a console in both modes the simplest solution is to call [`AllocConsole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) all the time.

> A process can be associated with only one console, so the AllocConsole function fails if the calling process already has a console. A process can use the FreeConsole function to detach itself from its current console, then it can call AllocConsole to create a new console or AttachConsole to attach to another console.